# PHP MULTIPLE UPDATE FUNCTION

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, dreamweaver

This program is not updating row records, any help :(

This program can't update multiple records in a rows, i need help
please... tnx

this is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
  require_once('Connections/tlsc_conn.php');
  mysql_select_db($database_tlsc_conn, $tlsc_conn);
  $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name";
  $Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $tlsc_conn) or die(mysql_error());
  $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $count = count($_POST['name']);
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='$name[$i]',lastname='$lastname[$i]', email='$email[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
        $row_Recordset1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }

    if($row_Recordset1){
        header("location:mulupdate.php");
        exit;
    }   
 }
?>
```

And this is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="634" border="1">
    <tr>
       <td>id</td>
       <td>name</td>
       <td>lastname</td>
       <td>email</td>
    </tr>
    <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php $id[]=$row_Recordset1['id']; ?><?php echo $row_Recordset1['id'];      ?></td>
      <td><input name="name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['name'];   ?>"></td>
       <td><input name="lastname[]" type="text" value="<?php echo   $row_Recordset1['lastname']; ?>"></td>
       <td><input name="email[]" type="text" value="<?php echo  $row_Recordset1['email']; ?>">
       </td>
    </tr>
     <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>

  </table>
   <p>
    <label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
     </label>
   </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to add variable, but still not working

Comment: Please don't SHOUT, you will succeed nothing with that.

Comment: If I was you, I would be more worried with the spaghetti code

Comment: no im not shouting, i just forget to lowercase my message, ok i'm sorry for that, please forgive me... :(

Comment: is there a spaghetti code, i know something like php cake

Answer (score 1):

I believe your SQL statement needs variables enclosed in {} if they are in double quotes `"`

```
$sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='{$name[$i]}',lastname='{$lastname[$i]}', email='{$email[$i]}' WHERE id='{$id[$i]}'";
```

as well you'll need to send back the id like so:

```
<input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id'];?>">
```

**EDIT:**

looking over your code it appears $name, $lastname, $email and $id are undefined and you need to do something like:

```
$sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='{$_POST['name'][$i]}',
lastname='{$_POST['lastname'][$i]}', email='{$_POST['email'][$i]}'
WHERE id='{$_POST['id'][$i]}'";
```

Comment: tnx for this, but still not working, and it gets my "row 1" blank when i submit the button, but the record is still in the database. what exactly about it? i'm trying to know why

Comment: I've been try it, but gets my "first row" blank the record when i submit it, and the remaining rows are still there, and the record of my "first row" is still on my database, why should it happening?

Answer (score 0):

you dont sent back the id to the update file..
try insert this in the html's `<form>` inside the loop :

```
<input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id'];   ?>">
```